# Pagination on custom post type going to 404 even after $page

Tags: wordpress, post, types, pagination

Help! I'm losing my mind!!

I have a page which displays my custom post type 'rm' which I need to paginate but when I click through to page 2, I'm  getting a 404 page even when I've used

```
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; ?>
```

I've trawled the internet for a solution but can't find anything. Does anyone have an idea to what is wrong?

Here is my custom post type registration -

```
<?php /* RM SHOWCASE CREATION */
add_action('init', 'rm_register');

function rm_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Rich media', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Creative', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Creative item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Creative'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Creative'),
    'new_item' => __('New Creative'),
    'view_item' => __('View Creative'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Creative'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'rich-media-showcase'),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'verticals','features','device'),
    'has_archive' => false
  );

register_post_type( 'rm' , $args );
```

} ?>

And here is my query...

```
<?php do_action('show_beautiful_filters', 'rm'); ?>
<?php // set up or arguments for our custom query
    $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $query_args = array(
       'post_type' => 'rm',
       'paged' => $paged,
    );
// create a new instance of WP_Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); // run the loop ?>
<a class="creativeURL" href="<?php the_field('creative_url'); ?>" target="_blank" >
    <article class="creative">
        <img class="creativeImg" src="<?php the_field('cover_photo'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </article>
</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if ($the_query->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
   <nav class="prev-next-posts">
      <div class="prev-posts-link">
        <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
      </div>
      <div class="next-posts-link">
         <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); // display newer posts link ?>
      </div>
   </nav>
<?php } ?>

<?php // clean up after our query
   wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <article>
   <h1>Sorry...</h1>
   <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
</article>
```

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you use ?page=2 instead of page/2 ??

Do you have a page with the same name of your Custom Post Type Archive??

Have you tried to resave your permalinks?

Comment: Strangely, I had no page with the same name as my custom post type  but changed the template file name, template admin name in the file and page slug and it's worked. Thanks